# Docker Daemon Socket: Permission denied (even after usermod)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm having permissions issues running `docker` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
There are lots of posts describing a fix with `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`, however, this does not work for me.

Here is the error:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ docker container ls
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Run the usermod

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Confirm that my username is in the docker group:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:129:myuser
```

Also tried:

1. Close terminal window.
2. Log out of Ubuntu and back in.

And then:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ docker container ls
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

... Same issue!

It works when I use `sudo`

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo !!
sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
18b3719b66d2        postgres:10.3       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   local-postgres10.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output from the command `sudo ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`?  Docker may require some configuration before it allows users other than `root` to access.  For example, on RedHat derivatives, the group is `dockerroot` and the packaged Docker needs to be configured to create the socket with that group.

Comment: 1st command:
`srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 26 18:37 /var/run/docker.sock`

2nd command: 
`docker:x:129:myuser`

Comment: That certainly looks setup correctly, the socket already has `rw` access for the `docker` group.  From the information you posted, I cannot see why the `myuser` would not have permission to access the socket.  AppArmor or SELinux interfering maybe?

Comment: @Adam does the output of the `$ groups` shell command indeed include `docker`? otherwise, you can try to logout and login again…

Comment: Note however that adding a given user to the `docker` group is risky! (especially if one does this for the main user account in one's personal workstation) because it implies any process of this user can smoothly get root privileges, cf. the doc [Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface)

Answer (score 0):

On a Centos 7.6 (`ami-04cf43aca3e6f3de3` on AWS) I found that the socket was owned by `root:root`, and the docker group is called `dockerroot` (see in `/etc/group`).

Resolved with a chgrp and a usermod, as following:

```
# ll /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw----. 1 root root 0 Mar 22 16:40 /var/run/docker.sock
# chgrp dockerroot /var/run/docker.sock
# usermod -aG dockerroot USER_HERE
# ll /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw----. 1 root dockerroot 0 Mar 22 16:40 /var/run/docker.sock

# su - USER_HERE
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE ...
...
```

Thanks to @gracefulrestart in the comments of the question for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause (hopefully more prevalent in 2022 than when this question was asked) is that when you're using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to SSH into an instance the user is ssm-user, not ec2-user.

To determine what user you're logged in with, run the following command:

```
whoami
```

If you googled a guide to install or configure Docker on Amazon Linux, you've probably configured everything for the `ec2-user` user and not for the `ssm-user` user, since that's what 99% of the guides out there tell you to do. If this is the case, run the command:

```
cat /etc/group | grep docker
```

You should see the following output:

```
docker:x:990:ec2-user
```

This will confirm that the `ec2-user` user is properly configured, but not the `ssm-user` user. To configure the `ssm-user` run the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker ssm-user
```

Then, to verify that it ran successfully, re-run the previous command and verify the output:

```
cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:990:ec2-user,ssm-user
```

Finally, **log out and log back in**.